# Is there a way to find a substring in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Well, I got this problem: 
I have a pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to find a the value that starts with "THRL-" and delete that exact same prefix, I've tried to make it a string and use the `result = df.toString()` method as it follows (Where result is a DataFrame):

```
a = result.replace('THRL-', '')
```

But it doesn't work, I still see the same THRL- prefix in the string that I'm returning.

Is there a better way to do it? I also tried with a dictionary but it didn't seem to work because apparently the method `.to_dict()` returns a list instead of a dictionary

Comment: did you try `df.replace('^THRL-', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: I had no idea that DataFrames had a replace method with built-in Regex it worked, thank you!